# How to compute normals of a set of unorganized triangled mesh as the picture?

Tags: cgal

[image: picture]

I addressed the result of Delauny triangulation of the point set, the result shown is not closed,so I can't use the ray shooting method.In the picture I just compute normal of every vertex,so it shows bright and dark.Is there a efficient method to get the normals of the triangles?

Answer (score 0):

The package on [Point Set Processing](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/packages.html#PkgPointSetProcessingSummary)  has a function [jet_estimate_normals()](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Point_set_processing_3/group__PkgPointSetProcessing.html#ga1ad4612080daddad4174f1f8863570d3)

Comment: Thank you very much ! I solved this problem first know the topology of the mesh,set the points of the triangles all in clock or con-clock . I got the wrong result because I didn't get the right topology.